# Navigator line is different than series line

Tags: highcharts

I'm not quite sure is this a bug or can be configured in Highstock.

I expect the navigator line to looks the same like the series line. With the red marker I drew how it should looks:

[image]

The numbers are really small and you can see the implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vangi/mfgwpsLn/1/

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: "container",
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            'x': 1413981042000,
                'y': 1.0307497910755359E-10
        }, {
            'x': 1414049332000,
                'y': 6.8937692958570551E-06
        }, {
            'x': 1414153012000,
                'y': 6.1638593534807384E-12
        }, {
            'x': 1414156468000,
                'y': 6.1457475393489336E-12
        }, {
            'x': 1414159924000,
                'y': 6.1549662935811433E-12
        }, {
            'x': 1414166836000,
                'y': 6.1692543434910263E-12
        }, {
            'x': 1414170292000,
                'y': 6.1634967962742593E-12
        }, {
            'x': 1414173748000,
                'y': 6.1702021530302131E-12
        }, {
            'x': 1414184401000,
                'y': 6.1611544859008216E-12
        }]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with y value, which should not cinaon E-12 value, but full number.

```
 data: [{
            'x': 1413981042000,
                'y': 1
        }, {
            'x': 1414049332000,
                'y': 6
        }, {
            'x': 1414153012000,
                'y': 1
        }, {
            'x': 1414156468000,
                'y': 1
        }, {
            'x': 1414159924000,
                'y': 1
        }, {
            'x': 1414166836000,
                'y': 1
        }, {
            'x': 1414170292000,
                'y': 1
        }, {
            'x': 1414173748000,
                'y': 1
        }, {
            'x': 1414184401000,
                'y': 1
        }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uykeoc3j/3/

Comment: When I remove the E notation the behavior will not change: http://jsfiddle.net/Vangi/mfgwpsLn/2/. I guess this is an issue of navigator that don't work with such small numbers. If there is no other solution I'll post a bug.

Comment: thanks for the workaround. But I expect the Highstock to make this for the navigatior data as for the series data.